# Nginx configured as reverse proxy 404 every other request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Nginx has been setup as a reverse proxy but when a request is made, every other request gives a 404 error. Checking the log of the application running on port 9000 shows that the request doesn't reach the application.

The configuration for the reverse proxy is:

```
server {
    listen 8088;
    listen [::]:8088;

    server_name www.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.com.error.log;

    location / {
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The part

```
add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
```

has been added to try to tackle the problem.

The access log shows the 200 and the 400 alternating:

```
x.x.x.x - - [02/Feb/2023:11:49:28 +0100] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
x.x.x.x - - [02/Feb/2023:11:50:41 +0100] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

This looks like a load balancer issue but no load balancer is installed. Doing multiple calls on localhost with `url -i http://localhost:9000/ping` doesn't show any problems.

Doing the same calls on localhost with the domain name, first call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2023 10:56:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 92
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Last-Modified: Thursday, 02-Feb-2023 10:56:55 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
```

and then the second call (and every other call):

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2023 10:56:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 19
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

404 page not found
```

There is a second Nginx service running in a docker container running on port 80. But this should not be an issue. The 404 is definitely coming from the non docker Nginx running as a service on the machine.

I can't find the issue at this moment, any advice where to look or what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the $request_uri as follow:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:9000$request_uri;
```

For proxying requests to the FastCgi servers (such as PHP-Fpm) use [fastcgi module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) and fastcgi_pass directive instead proxy_pass.

Comment: If I do that, I get a 502 bad gateway